# Inversion with ordinal scale

Tags: d3.js

Is there any way to find inversion of ordinal scale?

I am using string value on x axis which is using ordinal scale and i on mouse move i want to find inversion with x axis to find which string is there at mouse position?

Is there any way to find this?

```
var barLabels = dataset.map(function(datum) {
    return datum.image;
});
console.log(barLabels);
var imageScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(barLabels)
        .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.1);
// divides bands equally among total width, with 10% spacing.
console.log("imageScale....................");
console.log(imageScale.domain());

 .
 .
var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0];
xScale.invert(xPos);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I actually think it doesn't make sense that there *isn't* an invert method for ordinal scales, but you can figure it out using the ordinal.range() method, which will give you back the start values for each bar, and the ordinal.rangeBand() method for their width.

Example here:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dMpbh/2/

The relevant code is

```
    .on("click", function(d,i) {
        var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0];
        console.log("Clicked at " + xPos);
        //console.log(imageScale.invert(xPos));
        var leftEdges = imageScale.range();
        var width = imageScale.rangeBand();
        var j;
        for(j=0; xPos > (leftEdges[j] + width); j++) {}
            //do nothing, just increment j until case fails
        console.log("Clicked on " + imageScale.domain()[j]);
    });
```

Comment: Any way we can bring this up with Mike for future d3.js v4 enhancements?

Comment: @NickBraunagel Good suggestion, to actually make a formal suggestion! The place to do it would be the D3 GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/d3/d3/issues

Comment: @AmeliaBR nice, will do. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @AmeliaBR FYI - looks like Mike has already been asked this question.  Here is his respone: https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3022#event-857320381

Comment: Thanks for following up, @NickBraunagel. Glad to see there have been proposals & there's ongoing discussion, even if there is no ideal, clean solution.

Answer (score 20):

I found a shorter implementation [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/598/files) in [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/598) rejected pull request which worked perfectly.

```
var ypos = domain[d3.bisect(range, xpos) - 1];
```

where domain and range are scale domain and range:

```
var domain = x.domain(),
    range = x.range();
```

Answer (score 3):

I have in the past reversed the domain and range when this is needed

```
> var a = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range([0, w]);
> var b = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,w]).range([0, 100]);

> b(a(5));
5
```

However with ordinal the answer is not as simple. I have checked the documentation & code and it does not seem to be a simple way. I would start by mapping the items from the domain and working out the start and stop point. Here is a start.

```
imageScale.domain().map(function(d){
    return {
        'item':d,
        'start':imageScale(d)
    };
})
```

Consider posting your question as a feature request at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues?state=open in case

1. There is sufficient demand for such feature
2. That I haven't overlooked anything or that there is something more hidden below the documentation that would help in this case

Comment: I'd happily upvote that feature request (for an `ordinal.invert()` method).  As with the invert methods on the other scales, occasionally results wouldn't be valid, but most of the time it would be.  One would need some extra parameter to decide how to deal with values that equated to padding space, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know which mouse position corresponds to which data, then d3 is already doing that for you.

```
.on("click", function(d,i) {
    console.log("Clicked on " + d);
});
```

I have updated the Fiddle from @AmeliaBR http://fiddle.jshell.net/dMpbh/17/

Answer (score 1):

I recently found myself in the same situation as OP.

I needed to get the inverse of a categorical scale for a slider. The slider has 3 discrete values and looks and behaves like a three-way toggle switch. It changes the blending mode on some SVG elements. **I created an inverse scale with `scaleQuantize()` as follows:**

```
var modeArray = ["normal", "multiply", "screen"];
var modeScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(modeArray)
  .range([0, 120]);
var inverseModeScale = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain(modeScale.range())
  .range(modeScale.domain());
```

I feed this `inverseModeScale` the mouse x-position (`d3.mouse(this)[0]`) on drag:

```
.call( d3.drag()
    .on("start.interrupt", function() { modeSlider.interrupt(); })
    .on("start drag", function() { inverseModeScale(d3.mouse(this)[0]); })
)
```

It returns the element from `modeArray` that is closest to the mouse's x-position. Even if that value is out of bounds (-400 or 940), it returns the correct element.

Answer may seem a bit specific to sliders but posting anyway because it's valid (I think) and this question is in the top results for " *d3 invert ordinal* " on Google.

*Note: This answer uses d3 v4.*

Answer (score 0):

I understand why Mike Bostock may be reluctant to include `invert` on ordinal scales since you can't return a singular true value. However, here is my version of it.
The function takes a position and returns the surrounding datums. Maybe I'll follow up with a binary search version later :-)

```
function ordinalInvert(pos, scale) {
    var previous = null
    var domain = scale.domain()
    for(idx in domain) {
        if(scale(datum[idx]) > pos) {
            return [previous, datum[idx]];
        }
        previous = datum[idx];
    }
    return [previous, null];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by constructing a second linear scale with the same domain and range, and then calling invert on that.

```
  var scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(domain)
    .range(range);
  var continousScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(domain)
    .range(range)

  var data = _.map(range, function(i) {
    return continousScale.invert(i);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily get the object's index/data in callback

```
.on("click", function(d,i) {
    console.log("Clicked on index = " + i); 
    console.log("Clicked on data  = " + d); 
    // d == imageScale.domain()[1]
});
```

d is the  ***invert value itself***.
You don't need to use obj.domain()[index] .