# Hoverline of ordinal x-axis in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

How do i use the x.invert() function for hoverline in d3.js. It works when there is date on the x-axis but does not work where there is ordinal x-axis. I have been trying this for a week and still not found solution.

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]), i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1), d0 = data[i - 1], d1 = data[i], d = x0 - (d0.key) > (d1.key) - x0 ? d1 : d0; This is the code. Here the .invert() does not work....is there anyway of overcoming this?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinal scales do not have an invert function (since they are discrete). Only quantative and time scales does (which are continnous)

Since you do not provide a context of where you are trying to use it it is hard to give you an alternative solution. But check this question and the verified answer to get an idea of how you can solve your problem:
[Inversion with ordinal scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758373/inversion-with-ordinal-scale)

Comment: var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
     i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
     d0 = data[i - 1],
     d1 = data[i],
     d = x0 - (d0.key) > (d1.key) - x0 ? d1 : d0;

This is the code. Here the .invert() does not work....is there anyway of overcoming this?